# iPhone/Objective-C - Subclassing TTLauncherView methods to get pageChanged

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20, ttlauncherview

I would like to determine when a page changes in a `TTLauncherView` and some people have said I should subclass the method:

Original Post: http://groups.google.com/group/three20/browse_thread/thread/caf702363f3abaa8/862f69e52dcc3981

```
- (void)updatePagerWithContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset;
```

I'm not quite sure what they mean about subclassing?

I tried doing the following:

```
@interface TTLauncherView (MyExtensions)

- (void)updatePagerWithContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset;

@end

@implementation TTLauncherView (MyExtensions)

- (void)updatePagerWithContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset {
    NSLog(@"Foo");
}

@end
```

I'm not quite sure what this is meant to achieve though? I need to update a value depending on the `_launcherView.pager.currentPage`. There is currently no delegate method that allows the checking of what page you're currently on or when a page has changed (or maybe I don't know where to look). Also `_launcherView.pager.currentPage` is always 0 any way. *confused*

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are talking about inheritance.
more info here
http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html#inheritance

try this

```
@interface MyLauncher:TTLauncherView (MyExtensions)
{}
- (void)updatePagerWithContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset;

@end

@implementation MyLauncher (MyExtensions)

- (void)updatePagerWithContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset {
    NSLog(@"Foo");
}

@end
```